# Convert number to YYYYMM

Tags: string, excel, datetime, excel-formula, format

I have following numbers, which actually represent dates in the YYYYMM format:

```
201301
201302
201303
...
```

When I try to format the cells to date fields, Excel always overwrites the original dates and creates some crazy dates, that have nothing in common with the actual ones.

How can I bring Excel to convert it properly?

Comment: How do you want it to look like?

Comment: MMYYYY or YYYYMM, important is, that it's treated like a date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Excel (by default) uses the 1900 date system. This simply means that the date 1 Jan 1900 has a true numeric value of 1, 2 Jan 1900 has a value of 2 etc. These values are called "serial values" in Excel and it is these serial values that allows us to use dates in calculations.` [which was discussed here](http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/ExcelDateandTimes.htm).

So that explains why your data reflects a different date when you try to format is as *Date*.
What you need to do then is to transform it into a complete readable date format *Excel* recognize.
As is, Excel will use its default *Serial Value* conversion.

If you have your data in starting in A1, enter this in B1.

`=DATEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,LEFT(A1,4),LEFT(A1,4)&"-")&"-01")`

Above formula will then create a valid *Date* that Excel can interpret and read correctly.
Result will be:

```
41275
41306
41334
```

When you format it as *Date*, it will equate to the 1st day of every month.

```
1/1/2013
2/1/2013
3/1/2013
```

You can just fix the formatting using *Custom Format* to get YYYYMM as seen below:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, unfortunately that seems not to work in Excel 2003

Answer (score 2):

If your range is small enough (in the example all 2013) then no formula is required. Replace `13` with `13-`, apply Text to Columns with Tab as the delimiter and at Step 3 choose Date and YMD.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the DATE and LEFT/RIGHT functions.

Assuming that format is consistent (i.e. 4 characters for year, 2 characters for month), to convert cell A1:

```
=DATE(LEFT(A1,4), RIGHT(A1,2), 1)
```

This will assume the first day of the month for the date (I assume that's irrelevant for you). You can then format the cell as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use formula in Excel to solve this..

A sample formula is given below

```
=DATE(MID(CELLID,1,4),MID(CELLID,5,2), 1)
```

Comment: did you replace the cell id with A1, B1 etc. ?